# ArangoDB : Query based on networks size

Tags: arangodb

I would like to implement the following process :

- Import Edges from a csv file (I have seen in the documentation that Nodes importation from a csv file is doable, but not sure that is doable for edges). If so, an exemple would be welcome.
- I would like to make a query that will: take into account only networks bigger than a certain size (eg: keep networks with 16 nodes or more)
- Taking into account only these large networks, I would like to retrieve the list of all nodes from a certain type (eg nodes = UserID)

Is that doable with ArangoDB ?

Comment: How do you define a "network"?

Comment: A network is composed of nodes link together by edges. In some software such as Gephi  networks are defined by a component ID. For example node A and node B are connected together. Node C, node D and node E are connected together. Here we have 2 networks. In my example, I would like to take into account only the second network because the network size is greater than 2 nodes. And I would like to obtain as result Node E because node E is a UserID type. Is that clearer ?

Comment: Also known as connected components

Comment: Another approach woud be to remove all the "networks" with less than x nodes. Eventually coying all the large networks into another DB. The gaol is to isolate these networks for being able to extract some specific nodes. Does it make sense ?